# Populate SharePoint 2010 Calendar with email

Tags: 2010, email, calendar

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Is it possible to populate a SharePoint 2010 Calendar by just sending an email?

If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, however you will need to configure calendar to receive emails,

> The catch is that the calendar has to have been configured to allow it
>   to receive email but, if it has been, this nifty feature will be
>   available to you as an end user.  There are several ways you can find
>   out if an existing calendar has been set up to receive email, but
>   rather than shamelessly regurgitate those methods for you, I'm going
>   to hand the mic over to the Microsoft page where I learned all of
>   this:  Add an event to a SharePoint calendar by sending e-mail.
>
> If you'd care to set up a calendar on your own site that will accept
>   email, but you're worried that the configuration process is going to
>   be difficult, allow me to set your mind at ease.  Creating a calendar
>   that will allow users to add events by sending email is as simple as
>   navigating from Site Actions -> Create -> Calendar (it's under the
>   Tracking heading), and then on the resulting set-up screen, click the
>   Yes radio button in the Incoming E-Mail section, and assign an email
>   address, e.g.:

[image]

[Source](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2008/09/05/adding-an-event-to-a-sharepoint-calendar-via-email.aspx)

Comment: SharePoint 2010? Dont see the option to allow Incoming E-Mail anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, I think there's some thing wrong with that tutorial, do you want to follow this one, http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/08/16/configuring-incoming-email-for-sharepoint-2010-foundations.aspx